# MySQL how to store data + access permissions performance-wise

Tags: mysql, optimization, permissions

I've recently came across a problem for which I can only think of muddy solutions.

Imagine a table has several objects (lets say photos to make it easier). **Every single photo/object must have it's own set of permissions.**

1 - photo must always be seen by uploader
2 - photo belongs to a group of photos and all users that have access to that group can see it
3 - photo can be shut-out and made private
4 - photo can be "authorized" user-specific
5 - photo can be "denied" user-specific

Both the users and the groups of photos will grow to a moderate size.

I'm not looking for a SQL-detailed query here. Just hoping that someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are the photos public or private by standard?

Comment: @Anzeo all photos are private by standard. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to note I do not have much experience with optimizing SQl at this point, so it's possible my answer would impose too much load on the server.

I would opt for a table, say photo_permission who would contain a mapping between the user_id's and the authorized photo_id's for each user id. Something like:

```
| user_id | photo_id |
| 1       | 1        |
| 1       | 3        |
| 2       | 1        |
| 2       | 2        |
```

If a record exists for a certain user with id user_id and a certain photo with id photo_id, the user has permission to view the photo.

If you cannot block the photo from a user who has access to the group containing the photo, you could even simplify the above table

```
| authority_id | authority_type | photo_id |
| 1            | group          | 1        |
| 1            | user           | 3        |
| 2            | user           | 1        |
| 2            | group          | 2        |
```

Now you can check whether the user's id is listed on rows with authority_type user OR check whether his id is `IN (SELECT id FROM user where group_id=authority_id)` on rows with authority_type group. Note that the above code is not tested.

Comment: thanks for your answer. My line of though goes more or less to what you described (I just didn't put it up on asking so I wouldn't pollute the results). One thing we can do to speed up the query is to turn it around and instead of starting with photos we can start by querying the user (as the query is always gonna be relative to some user).

Comment: @Frankie, your welcome. Could you clarify what you mean by turning around the query?

Comment: instead of searching ALL photos that match XYZ user search for USER XYZ that matches SOME photos. I'm still hoping that some SQL guru will see this question and enlighten us both on THE way to do this right.